# Docker Compose with Multiple Networks

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file that specifies two containers which are to be created in two separate networks:

1. A mysql database -- this contains the adventureworks data (and belongs to `adventureworks-db-nw` network).
2. A java based webapp -- this talks to the mysql database to perform CRUD operations (and belongs to `adventureworks-app-nw` network).

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
    adventureworks-db:
        image: mysql
        container_name: adventureworks-db
        networks: 
            - adventureworks-db-nw
        ports:
            - 3306:3306
    adventureworks-app:
        container_name: adventureworks-app
        networks: 
            - adventureworks-app-nw
        ports:
            - 8080:8080

networks: 
    adventureworks-db-nw:
        driver: bridge
    adventureworks-app-nw:
        driver: bridge
```

For brevity, I have omitted certain parts of the docker-compose.yml file that will perhaps not be relevant to the question I have.

How can I get the java webapp in `adventureworks-app` container, that belongs to the `adventureworks-app-nw` to talk to the mysql database in `adventureworks-db` container, that belongs to the `adventureworks-db-nw` network?

Please note that I want to maintain the separation of these two networks as two separate custom (user-created) docker networks.

Comment: Why wouldn't the app be on the same network as the database?

Comment: @OneCricketeer They typically would be. But in this particular scenario, I'm trying to mock a non dockerized ecosystem. The app resides in a separate network, the MQ (for ex, Kafka) is hosted by some provider on their own network,  the database is hosted by some other provider on their own network, etc. I'm using containers to represent individual services that are typically going to be provided by different providers on separate networks..

Comment: In that case, you need to model the router/proxy as well that allows you to interact between those two different networks. In other words **something** is responsible for routing traffic between networks. Otherwise, you will run into the issue you have now

Comment: @OneCricketeer Yep, exactly. How can I go about modelling a router/proxy between two docker networks?

Comment: Traefik is one example that I know of, but it would be easier to just allow the Java app to exist on the database network rather than remodeling external network infrastructure.

Comment: Will check it out. Thanks @OneCricketeer

Answer (score 0):

If you want the java app to communicate with the db container via it's service name, then you would have to add the "adventureworks-db-nw" network to the app service.

If you don't want to do that then since you are exposing the ports I guess you should be able to connect by using the host ip/hostname and the exposed port.